# Locally testing OS environmental variables in Ballerina

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, ballerina

When using Ballerina `configurable`s we can use a `config.toml` to maintain the configurations and compile the service without any issue.

If I need to use a `os:getEnv("variable")` in Ballerina, is there a way to mount this file in local environment and compile the service?

Thank you.